# Getting RestTemplate (Connection Reset) Despite everything is correct

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, httpconnection, spring-resttemplate, connection-reset

I'm using Spring Boot RestTemplate to call REST API.

On PROD, I'm getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://<host>/v2/graphql": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
```

The request from client is reached to gateway and gateway also forwarded it to the server. Server has successfully processed the request, but the connection was reset in less than 5 secs.

These are the http configs for the RestTemplate:

```
connectionRequestTimeoutMs: 3000
connectTimeoutMs: 3000
readTimeoutMs: 3000
maxConnectionsTotal: 100
maxConnectionsPerRoute: 100
```

In total 2300 requests, only 8 requests are failed with connection reset error, but I want to understand why this is happening.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to answer, many things could be killing your connection on the gateway end.  If you are saying some requests are failing, maybe look at the different in those requests vs the other ones.  Are those ones taking longer than the others that pass?

Comment: and you do realize the values you put for connectTimeoutMS  and others are in milliseconds?  So basically it means 3 seconds.....

Comment: Yeah, that's true - those in milliseconds. Couldn't get a way through. Added a retry and it's working so far.

Comment: Can you share your resttemplate config or is it just the default one? If you are using a pooling connection manager, you may consider adding keepalive connection strategy and evicting your connections in certain interval.